# apprequests dialog does not function in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I am using the following javascript line to open a facebook app requests dialog:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'A request especially for one person.',
        data: 'tracking information for the user' 
        });
```

When I click on the button that is to open this dialog in Firefox, it works just fine.  However, in Chrome, the new window pops open, and immediately closes before any user action is taken.

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Do you have some sort of popup blocker in chrome?  Also, you should try and use display=iframe if you can.

Comment: After changing it to use an iframe, it still doesn't work in chrome, and no longer works in Firefox, and I discovered I am having the same problem in IE as Chrome, doesn't work with either page or iframe display types

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with chrome.
I fixed the problem by deactivating some add ons in the chrome settings, which may have been maleware, adblocker etc... now everything works as expected.